# jQuery Tools Tooltip: show on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, jquery-tooltip

I am working on a small app and am using jQuery Tools Tooltip ( http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip/index.html ) for the tooltip functionality. I can't figure out how to show the tooltip on page load. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Without a sample to provide you, I feel guilty making this an "answer"... so a comment it is! All you need to do is initialize your tooltip in the jQuery "document ready" function. Then there's a method in the API for `.show()` but I didn't fully investigate its exact syntax. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! There are two different ways to do this (after seeing the answer below and your comment)... I am posting them below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to trigger the mouseenter event on page load after you initalize the tooltip.

```
$("#target").mouseenter();
```

Comment: DUDE! Thanks so much! I knew this was simple! I will accept it once Stackoverflow will let me LOL! Thanks again!

Comment: When there's an API call for `show()` this seems a bit sideways; however, you can't argue with the results! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

After seeing the answer from Matthew and the suggestion from Greg, there are two ways (could be more) of going about doing this.

Here they are.

**Using jQuery Tools' API Version**

```
$('.searchToolTip').tooltip({
                    position: 'bottom center'
                });

                var tooltipApi = $('.searchToolTip').data('tooltip');
                tooltipApi.show();
```

**Using jQuery to activate mouseEnter()**

```
$('.searchToolTip').tooltip({
                    position: 'bottom center'
                }).mouseenter();
```

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: +1 Using the API as intended is less hacky than triggering fake events. (Although it was not obvious to me exactly how to use this API. The data() method was a surprise to me.)

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like all of the tooltips have '.tooltip' so you could do this.

```
$(function(){
    $('div.tooltip').fadeIn();
});
```

You'll probably want to add some logic to '.fadeOut()' as well